# How to notify RecyclerView in adapter class to update when changes occur in room database

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to update my recycler view data when a user deletes an item from the room database. I tried `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the adapter but it's not updating.

this is my adapte's codes

```
public class WatchlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WatchlistAdapter.MyHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    List<Task> watchList;



    public WatchlistAdapter(Context mContext, List<Task> watchList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.watchList = watchList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.watch_list_layout, parent, false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {
        Task t = watchList.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(t.getTitle());
        holder.type.setText(t.getType());

        holder.deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(V->{
            deleteItem(t);
            Log.d("myapp", "deleted:"+ t.toString());
            notifyDataSetChanged();



        });


    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return watchList.size();
    }

    public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title;
        TextView type;
        ImageView deleteIcon;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_name);
            type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            deleteIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        }
    }

    private void deleteItem(final Task task){
        class Delete extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                DatabaseClient.getInstance(mContext)
                        .getAppDatabase()
                        .taskDao()
                        .delete(task);

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                super.onPostExecute(unused);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Removed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
        Delete dt = new Delete();
        dt.execute();

    }
}
```

Comment: You've chosen to handle the configuration change yourself. That means you, not the system, needs to manually swap every single thing that needs to change. Why are you saying you want to handle orientation changes when you seem to want the default behavior of automatically swapping out resources?

Comment: I am a beginner in native app development, I'm just trying out some pieces of stuff.so I'm not sure ...

Comment: How should I fix this manually??

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for your reference.

1.1 Change `AndroidManifest.xml`

Add the following content to the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

landscape ：
`android:screenOrientation=”landscape”`

portrait :
`android:screenOrientation=”portrait”`

1.2 `setRequestedOrientation` (Code Settings)

landscape：
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

portrait：
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`